# Simple SwiftUI transition that doesn't seem to be working

Tags: xcode, animation, swiftui, transition

I've been trying to get a comprehensive understanding of how Animations and Transitions work in SwiftUI.

I've been experimenting with different transitions and animations all day but one transition I want isn't working. I'll first show the code and then explain what sort of transition I want.

```
struct Test: View {
    @State private var pressed = false // Controls whether the tower is shown or not.

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(pressed ? "Press me to hide tower" : "Press me to show tower") {  // Controls truth value of the "pressed" variable above.
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 5)) {  // I've set the duration to 5 because I want to see the animation in slow-motion.
                    self.pressed.toggle()  // Toggles truth value of "pressed" from true to false or vice-versa.
                }
            }

            if pressed {  // Displays the Tower when "pressed" is true.
                Tower()  // Tower struct is provided below.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the Tower struct:

```
struct Tower: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Level 3").transition(.move(edge: .leading))
            Text("Level 2")
            Text("Level 1").transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
        }
    }
}
```

The transition I want to achieve is pretty straightforward - I want Level 3 to fly in from the left, Level 1 to fly in from the right, and Level 2 to just fade in and out. With this code however, Levels 1, 2 and 3, all just fade in and out together. The `.move(edge: .trailing)` transition seems to not work for some reason.

The catch is that I definitely want the `Tower` struct and the `Test` struct to be separate at all times. 
(I don't want to copy-paste any of the code that's within the Tower struct inside of the Test struct)

If you can show me how I can make the upper and lower levels fly in from different sides please let me know (if you can provide a code sample as well it'll help a ton).

Answer (score 3):

Transition is an engine to *present/remove* a view in/from view hierarchy (with animation if animation is specified). It is applied to view as a whole, directly, and is not *passed-into* view's subviews. So if you try to add view into view hierarchy that does not have own transition it just appears, immediately, if there is animation then by default fade-in/out transition is applied (again, to view *as a whole*).

But you want to transition view's internals from outside. So here is possible solution.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 (you can play with animations by yourself)

[image: demo]

```
struct Test: View {
    @State private var pressed = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(pressed ? "Press me to hide tower" : "Press me to show tower") {
                self.pressed.toggle()
            }

            Tower(show: $pressed)
        }.animation(.easeInOut)
    }
}

struct Tower: View {
    @Binding var show: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if show {
                Text("Level 3").transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                Text("Level 2")
                Text("Level 1").transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut)
    }
}
```